# MailChimp Response Parsing Error in Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mailchimp

When I call the Mail Chimp Service using Ajax Call, time response is succesful, but it gives following error to parse response:

[image]

#### Code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",        //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: "http://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",         
    api_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},
    data: "",       //Data sent to server
    contentType: "",        // content type sent to server
    dataType: "json",   //Expected data format from server
    processdata: false,     //True or False
    success: function (json) {//On Successful service call
        var result = json.name;
        $("#dvAjax").html(result);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed    // When Service call fails
});
```

Comment: Check the devtools of your browser to see the actual response. My guess is that you can't call the MailChimp API from a browser at all.

Comment: You're almost there. Click on the link to see what the response looks like.